# bundle install does not find my gem!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, bundler

I am using simplegeo and the gem in rubygems.org is not up to date, so I user this line in my gemfile:

```
gem 'sg-ruby', :git => 'https://github.com/simplegeo/simplegeo-ruby.git'
```

And it worked fine, but today, I removed this line, ran `bundle install`, restore the gemfile with simplegeo, re-ran `bundle install`, and now I cannot get rid of the following:

```
Updating https://github.com/simplegeo/simplegeo-ruby.git
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'sg-ruby (>= 0, runtime)' in https://github.com/simplegeo/simplegeo-ruby.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'sg-ruby (>= 0, runtime)'
```

here is my gemfile (FYI)

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem "compass", ">= 0.10.4"          # The CSS framework
gem "ruby-debug", ">= 0.10.3"       # enable debug (vital!)
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2"  # The de-facto standard pagination gem for table in rails
gem 'hassle', :git => 'git://github.com/koppen/hassle.git', :group => :production # In order to use compass on heroku (read-only)
gem 'jquery-rails'  # using jquery instead of prototype with just a gem
gem 'delorean'      # getting back in time for testing purposes
gem 'sg-ruby', :git => 'https://github.com/simplegeo/simplegeo-ruby.git'       # SimpleGeo gem
```

I'm stuck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lib was renamed
 look at this change 
[link](https://github.com/simplegeo/simplegeo-ruby/commit/b4f87b5886e5594b03fc8fd713af34ed44436ae4)
use simplegeo instead of sg-ruby

Answer (score 4):

Did you try with this address:
git://github.com/simplegeo/simplegeo-ruby.git

instead of
https://github.com/simplegeo/simplegeo-ruby.git'

Cheers